# New Promise output returning the words "Promise { }"

Tags: json, node.js, promise

I'm working in a code with Promise to get JSON values, the code is working, but the output aways return between the words Promise {  }.

```
const info = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var req = require('request');


    var options = {
        url: 'https://api.info.com/',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'request'
        }
    };
    req(options, function (err, response, body) {
        if (!err && response.statusCode === 200) {
            resolve(JSON.parse(body));

        }
    });
});
console.log(info); //Output: Promise { [ { name: 'Gary'}, { name: 'John'} ] }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I'd like my output was only as in the website:

```
[ { name: 'Gary'}, { name: 'John'} ]
```

**==> UPDATE**
It's works partially:

```
const info = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var req = require('request');


    var options = {
        url: 'https://api.info.com/',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'request'
        }
    };
    req(options, function (err, response, body) {
        if (!err && response.statusCode === 200) {
             resolve(JSON.parse(body));

         }
    });
});
info.then(function(value) {console.log(value)});//output: [ { name: 'Gary'}, { name: 'John'} ]
```

but, I need to use the result outside of *then* to perform others queries operations using this Json result, I tried something like that:

```
info.then(function(value) { jsonfile = value });
console.log(jsonfile);//Output: jsonfile is not defined
```

Comment: It's a promise; not sure what you expect--you're logging it immediately instead of waiting for it. By the time it's logged it's resolved, but you're logging out the promise itself.

Comment: You can not do that as this is an asynchronous call and if you really want this kind of response the use await key word.https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-async-await-in-node-js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're console.logging the promise object. If you want the data from the resolve action, you can chain a function that uses that data.
ex:

```
const info = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var req = require('request');


    var options = {
        url: 'https://api.info.com/',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'request'
        }
    };
    req(options, function (err, response, body) {
        if (!err && response.statusCode === 200) {
            resolve(JSON.parse(body));

        }
    });
});
//On resolve, perform some function to the returned value (This can be replaced with a function call)
info.then(function(value) {console.log(value)});
```

More examples and details can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Edit in response to comment (i don't have the rep to post comments): Promises are synchronous, while code not inside the promise or then() is not treated synchronously. This is worth mentioning because while you *could* a sign your value to a global variable or define your var 'value' before the promise, 'value' may not have been resolved by the promise yet, meaning you have introduced a race condition. Instead, if you need the data from your promise in another function (they need to run sequentially), that function should be invoked in your then().

Ex:

```
info.then(function(value){
otherfunction(value);
});

function otherfunction(val) {
//does whatever you need to value and will occur after the promise above resolves
}
```

Comment: It was useful, but now I cannot use de var **value** outside of **then**:

            coinmarketinfo.then(function (value) {
                var data = value );                   
            });
            console.log(data);

Comment: You need to either store your value in a global variable (See my answer for problems with this approach) or chain your new function so it executes after the promise concludes.

Answer (score 0):

`info` is a pending promise. You need to `await` of use `.then` on it

Sample code

```
const info = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  var req = require('request');


  var options = {
    url: 'http://httpbin.org/get',
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'request'
    }
  };
  req(options, function (err, response, body) {
    if (!err && response.statusCode === 200) {
      resolve(JSON.parse(body));

    }
  });
});
console.log(info); // Promise { <pending> }
info.then((result) => console.log(result)); // api result
```